# Is This Single Node.JS App Using Multiple Cores?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, multiprocessing

On an Ubuntu 18.04 system running only 1 Node.js script that ingests a data feed, `htop` shows that both CPU cores are being utilized.

**With 1 node script running:**
[image]

**With NO node.js script running:**
[image]

This Node.js script has multiple event listeners that receives data, does some data processing and sends them to a remote database server.

```
foo.on('msg', msg => { setImmediate(() => do_work(msg)) } );
```

**Question:** Why does it appear as if both CPU cores are being utilized rather equally by Node, despite Node.js being single threaded? CPU load splits observed are 60%/40% and 50%/50%

Is it actually utilizing both CPU cores? Or simply switching between them really quickly all the time, but only really utilizing 1 core at any one time? In other words, such a scenario will cause the system to choke when the CPU workload is above 1 core's worth but lesser than 2 core's.

Basically, I like to know whether a single-core system will suffice for this work load. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK at least garbage collector runs in its own thread.

Comment: There are four instances of node are running (first picture).

Comment: @Xaqron I have only ran the node.js script once. Other than the garbage collector, what can the other 3 processes be for? Handling asynchronous function calls?

Answer (score 7):

Even though only a single JS function (per environment)<sup>1</sup> will execute at any given time, on one core, that doesn't mean

- that it always is the same core - the OS can move the thread at will (see [Why does a single threaded process execute on several processors/cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8485947/1048572), [Single-threaded application being balanced across CPU cores?](https://serverfault.com/q/411665/492195), [Why is a single thread spread across CPU's?](https://superuser.com/q/26240/175275), or [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/349972/66652))
- that the node.js runtime itself is singlethreaded. It might do processing of asynchronous work in background threads, it might run garbage collection (see [Can garbage collection happen while the main thread is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52740509/1048572) or [Garbage Collector and concurrent marking in V8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762751/1048572)), and more.

<sub>1: you mention that you're running only a single script, which means there is only one realm of JS objects. Another possibility for a node.js app to run on multiple threads is to spawn [workers](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), each of which has its own JS environment and communicates via events.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The fact that multiple node instances are running (while you ran the script once) means this is neither an internal `node` mechanism nor using [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) by script to utilize CPU.

Either the script or one of the libraries used by it, is trying to utilize CPU via the old fashion forking ([child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)) way which results in isolated (no shared memory) instances of `node` (multiple processes as in your case) which communicate via [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: My suspicion was the same, that a library is doing a fork or spawn or something.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I'm using Sequelize.js ORM with connection pools. The node.js event listener functions always send a database query at about 1000 queries/sec. Do you think it is possible Sequelize.js is the library that is causing this fork/spawn?